# Setting a form as parent c#

Tags: c#, transparency

How I can set Form1, parent for another form Form2, so I could use `Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;` ?

Comment: If your use `ShowDialog` to show Form2, then Form1 is Form2's  Parent. Or you could use `Show(this)`

Answer (score 0):

For opening Form2 as Child Of Form1 use the code :

in form1 :

```
Form2 fr=new Form2();
fr.Parent=this;
fr.show();
```

Or use :

```
Form2 fr=new Form2();
fr.show(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 loginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
 loginForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Of course the child for will now be a blocking form (dialog) of the parent window, if that isn't desired then just replace ShowDialog with Show..

```
 loginForm.Show(this);
```

You will still need to specify the StartPosition though.